# How to use delegate methods in a custom UISearchBar subclass

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates, uisearchbar

I am trying to create a custom UISearchBar, but am having trouble when trying to use the delegate methods of a UISearchBar. I am using the following code but it is not working? What am I doing wrong?

```
class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    var searchDelegate: UISearchBarDelegate

    init(del: UISearchBarDelegate) {
        self.searchDelegate = delegate
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        sizeToFit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        print(searchText)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a couple things I figured out a way around accessing the delegate. I used `searchTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchBar(_:)), for: .editingDidEnd)`. This allows me to access when the text was changed in the UISearchBar.

Answer (score 0):

step 1. Make sure your View Controller conforms UISearchBarDelegate:

```
class YourVC: UISearchBarDelegate {
```

step 2. add a delegate to your search bar:

```
yourSearchBar.delegate = self
```

step 3. finally add the textDidChange method:

```
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        print(searchText)
        // Do whatever you want with your search text
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the init(del: UISearchBarDelegate) initializer, you are trying to initialize the superclass UISearchBar, but you are not setting its delegate. And also CustomSearchBar class should override the UISearchBarDelegate.

I fixed and update your code, try

```
class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar {

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.delegate = self
        self.sizeToFit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

// Conform to the UISearchBarDelegate protocol
extension CustomSearchBar: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        print(searchText)
    }
}
```

Comment: But this will fail when the creator of the search bar sets itself as the delegate.

Answer (score -1):

The class that should implement the UISearchBarDelegate protocol is the ViewController where you will display this search bar. In the view controller you would have something like this:

```
class VC: UIViewController {

    let searchBar = CustomSearchBar()

    searchBar.delegate = self
}

extension VC: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        print(searchText)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to create a custom search bar that has a tableview that appears and changes sizes to give recommendations based on what is typed, that is why I want to know why the text is changed. Using the UISearchBarDelegate doesn't let me do this. Is there a way to do this without implementing it in the UIViewController?

Comment: But your search bar and tableview will be inside a view controller, right?

Comment: Yes, I guess I could technically do this in the view controller but it would be easier to implement multiple times if I implement it as a custom class